# Is it possible to pass a value from the controller to an input box in a jsp page in a Spring application?

Tags: javascript, jsp, spring-mvc

[image: Screenshot of application]

If you look at the screenshot of my application you can see I have a number of values in the input boxes. These values are ratings being called from Googles Places API, stored in javascript variables, and then assigned an ID so it can be called in the input tag. For example the restaurant:

```
// Passing the rating to a TextBox via getElementById. 
// averageRatingRounded is the value being passed into the input box. 
// Calculated by getting average of all ratings with a 1km radius of users searched location.

 var averageRatingTB = document.getElementById('restaurantAvgRating');
 averageRatingTB.value = averageRatingRounded;
```

I'm then calling the value from above like so

```
<p>Restaurants: &nbsp; &nbsp;<input type="text"  size="10" name="restaurantAvgRating" id="restaurantAvgRating"/>&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<button class="btn btn-default get_map" type="submit"
                onclick="clearMarkers();RestaurantReport();">Full Report</button></p>
```

I have other values that I want to enter into the "Average House Price" and "Crime Ratings" input boxes but these are coming from the Controller class within my Spring application. I have the values ready to be passed to the JSP page via model.addAttribute().

```
model.addAttribute("houseprice", housePriceAverage);
```

While I understand passing the values into the input box might not be the most efficient way of passing the values to the front end, is it possible to pass the values from the controller to input boxes in a jsp page?

Comment: `model.addAttribute` is the common way of passing values to the view from the controller. Why wouldn't it be efficient?

Comment: Sorry, I meant passing the values into an input box might not be the most efficient method of posting the values. Would you know how I could pass the values from model.addAttribute to the input box?

Comment: add attribute `value="${houseprice}"` to the input tag

Comment: So for example `Average House Price: <input type="text"  size="10" value="${houseprice}"/>` instead of something like `<input type="text"  size="10" name="houseprice" id="houseprice"/>`?